# Highlight items of a listview without using onTouch or onItemClick

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using a default array adapter to display my `listview`.

How do I highlight specific rows from my `listview` without touching anything i.e. without using `onTouch()` or `onItemClick()` (Just by using a code!) ?

Comment: In your adapter class, inside the getView([...]) method, you've to implement the algorithm you want. 

You want to highlight with wich specific pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the way you should do it is use custom adapter and in getVew function highlight the row you needed

e.g.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final Holder holder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
... 
if(position==thePositionYouNeed)
row.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

Comment: Using `setSelected` and an appropiate selector instead of `setBackgroundColor` would be more elegant

Comment: yep that will work too if states of item are required

Comment: Could you please provide me a link to how I can use it

Comment: there are millions of examples if you google it like this one 
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429